# Html file upload file with drag and drop support

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, file-upload

I would like to create a file-upload field where users can just drag and drop a file onto a certain area in the browser window.

Does this work with all modern browsers?

thanks!

Comment: first try it. if u find any error, we'll fix it

Comment: Chrome on Linux seems to respond "properly" in XFCE to a file being dropped on an `<input>` with type "file", for what that's worth :-)

Answer (score 2):

I found this plugin quite nice:

http://valums.com/ajax-upload/

The page has a live demo where you can drag and drop a file that gets uploaded.

Unfortunately, it only works in Chrome and Firefox, other browsers have to press a button!

Comment: The link is broken....